# ThingsBoard - How to get user details (example: Email) (not Customer) in Rule chain?

Tags: thingsboard

ThingsBoard - How to get user details/attributes (example: Email) in Rule chain?. there is rule chain node for getting customer attributes but not for customer users. Any idea will help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that rulechain operation are asychronus, they happen outside the current user, customer and session. So the rule chain has no idea who is the current user.

To get what you want you can make a HTTP call, with the swagger Api for exemple, using the Rest calls node. You will need the user Id and a JWT to perform this operation.

Or you can try by creating a relation with the user and by changing originator of the message with the change originator node. Once you changed the originator you can use the Enrichment nodes to get what you need.

If you need it to be dynamic try creating the relation with the create relation node in the rule chain.

Answer (score 0):

The way I get customer user details is to first use the "transformation to group by group name" [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtDXN.jpg). Then use originator fields to add email.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).